# How can I use the filename of an image in various variables in Java?

Tags: java, image, loops, arduino, processing

My code loads and draws images to screen. Each image has a four digit name, e.g., `0102.png`. The first two digits (`01`) define the image number and other two (`02`) define display duration of the image.

How can I get the filenames of the images and use them in a loop and in other variables?

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort; 
int n, dataIn;
int maxImages = 5;
int imageIndex = 0; 
PrintWriter output;
int i, j, k;
int a = 20;
String s, p;

void setup()
{
    size(100, 100);

    output = createWriter("a.txt");
    myPort = new Serial(this, "COM6", 38400);

    PImage[] images = new PImage[maxImages];     

    for (j = 0; j < images.length; j++) 
    {
        images[j] = loadImage(j + ".png");
        frameRate(1);
        images[j].loadPixels();
        imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.length;     
    }
}

void draw()
{
    function();
    //image(images[j], 0, 0);  
}
```

Comment: looping time of , can you explain what that means?

Comment: looping time means is that i want to run image in  a  loop n times.

Comment: sorry, still not sure what you mean. I have image "1.jpg" and I want to run it in a loop 2 times - what does that mean? You want to draw it 2 times?

Comment: @vs97 It's possible Asker's "looping" means "duration of display". Maybe it's a timer value before displaying next image?... I'm just guessing, though.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Yes, as long as you keep this information somewhere (or extracts it every time you need it)". It could be much easier, though: instead of having an array of PImage, you could have an array of a class you designed which would contains all the informations you need, a little bit like this:

```
class MyImage {
  protected PImage _image;
  protected PVector _size, _location;
  protected int _imageNumber;
  protected int _loopingTime;

  public MyImage(String imagePath, int imageNumber, int loopingTime, PVector location) {
    _image = loadImage(imagePath);
    _size = new PVector(_image.width, _image.height);
    _location = location;
    _imageNumber = imageNumber;
    _loopingTime = loopingTime;
  }

  public void SetImageLocation(int xx, int yy) {SetImageLocation(new PVector(xx, yy));}
  public void SetImageLocation(PVector v) {_location = v;}
  public int GetImageNumber() {return _imageNumber;}
  public int GetLoopingTime() {return _loopingTime;}
  public PVector GetSize() {return _size;}
  public PVector GetLocation() {return _location;}

  public void DrawImage(){
    image(_image, _location.x, _location.y, _size.x, _size.y);
  }
}
```

And later in your code you can initialize an array of this class instead of an array of PImage! Of course I designed this quickly, so you would do well to enrich it with everything you need.

I'll stay around if you have any questions. Have fun!